# Symfony3.4: PHPUnit and no code coverage driver available

Tags: php, visual-studio, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit

In my case:

When I run

> `vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-html coverage`

Error Comes:

> ```
>  PHPUnit 6.5.8 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
>  Error:         No code coverage driver is available
> ```

Then I installed Xdebug

> `sudo apt-get install php-xdebug`

But When I again run
`vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-html coverage`

**It gives the error:**

> ```
> PHPUnit 6.5.8 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> Undefined variable: view
> ```

Comment: `Undefined variable: view` means that you have an error and that you fixed the issue with code coverage. I think that you can remove the part about Xdebug because it's not a part of the problem. IIRC, running `vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-html coverage -vv` should give you more information.

Comment: @A.L I did you say but still didn't get anything  :      `vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-html coverage -vv
PHPUnit 6.5.8 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 7.1.20-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 with Xdebug 2.6.0
Configuration: /var/www/html/con/phpunit.xml.dist

Undefined variable: view`

Comment: You can add the `--debug` option in order to see the failing test.

Answer (score 0):

In your test class, you probably use a variable named "view" that hasn't been initialized

Comment: no i didn't used any view variable

Comment: The variable may be in a controller, a service, etc.